# シェルスクリプトからApplescriptで記述したアプリを実行し、その動作の成否を戻り値で返したい

Tags: macos, bash, applescript

Applescriptで記述したアプリを、シェルから起動して実行しています。
正しくアプリが動作したのか、エラーが起きたのか、戻り値を返したいのですが
どうすればいいでしょうか。

```
#!/bin/sh

Open /Users/user/hoge.app
exit
```

hoge.app

```
tell application "System Preferences"
activate
set current pane to pane "com.apple.Network-Link-Conditioner"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
tell process "System Preferences"
    tell window "Network Link Conditioner"
        click button "ON"
        tell group 1
            click pop up button 1

            click menu item "3G" of menu 1 of pop up button 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
end tell
```

Comment: `$?` を使えば？Openが成功かどうかを表示するはずですか。。。

Comment: 「スクリプトがうまく実行できたか、AppleScript上で何か対処しなければ」と思い込んでいましたが、Openの成否を確認すればよいのですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Open /Users/user/hoge.app
```

$?でOpenした時の戻り値を調べました。

成功時

```
 user$ $?
 -bash: 0: command not found
```

失敗時（アプリ上で呼び出している、Network Link Conditionerが無かった場合）

```
 user$ $?
 -bash: 127: command not found
```

[image: アプリのエラー画面]

同時に、アプリのほうでは、このようなエラー画面が出ました。